# gdb wont break on "futex"

Tags: linux, gdb, futex

I'm running strace on my process to monitor performance and I see a lot of calls like so:

```
futex(0x3d89d68, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
...
```

I'm trying to catch where this call is being done in gdb ( just like I do for other system calls ).  However when I try to break on futex gdb doesnt recognize the symbol:

```
(gdb) b futex
Function "futex" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

Is there some special way to break on futex calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [futex syscall manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html):

> glibc provides no wrapper for futex()

So instead of `break`, you’ll need to use the GDB command `catch syscall futex` to suspend the program when it starts that syscall.

Comment: That's awesome, this works.  Do you know if its also possible to set this break on a specific thread?

Comment: @ByteMe95  Unfortunately, the `catch` command doesn't take a `thread` argument  (`break` does), but you can get close. You can use the `condition` command to tell GDB to evaluate an expression each time the catchpoint is hit; when it's true, the program will be suspended and you'll get a GDB prompt.  For example, after setting a catchpoint whose number is 1, you can type `condition 1 $_thread == 3` to suspend the program only when the catchpoint is hit in thread ID 3.

Comment: I just gave this a try, didnt seem to break at all when setting the condition like that.  I tried providing the gdb thread id and the LWP thread id